# neon shift instruction, can vector shift by vector?

Tags: arm, neon

I want to use neon instruction to speed up my program, I need to use the shift operation, but I only found Vector shift by constant. So is there a Vector shift by vector? for `vshr_n_s8` instruction, Can parameter `__b` be a vector?

```c
int8x8_t vshr_n_s8 (int8x8_t __a, const int __b);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you can use [`int8x8_t vshl_s8(int8x8_t a, int8x8_t b);`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0491/i/Using-NEON-Support/Shifts-by-signed-variable) with the elements of the vector `b` positive for a left shift and negative for a right shift.  (`vneg_s8` could be useful if you have a vector of positive shift counts but want a right shift.)  There are also signed/unsigned and saturating/rounding versions.